# Place a label on the image?

Tags: php, html

I got a page here http://183.78.169.53/tyre2/page2.html. For now is static but I will be reading from the database and form something like this dynamically. The problem as I read position ID from the db and would like to place on each of the tyres? Any idea how to achieve it?

Comment: Dear Michael,Yes I will be using the php to read from mysql db? Any idea how to put the labels?

Answer (score 2):

There are a fews ways to put labels on images in web applications.

1. Make an HTML element like a div or span, whose css `background` property is an image.  You will have
   to change the css dynmaically if the image is read from a database.
2. Generate a new image by compositing the text and background image server-side (but that is sooooo 1990s!)
3. Generate the whole display using `<canvas>`

Given what you have already, I would go with option 1.

Comment: Personal thought: It may be `sooooo 1990s`, but it is also sooooo easy... You're right in suggesting CSS first (+1 by the way), but come on, how many of us wouldn't be tempted with "You know, it's just this once..."

Comment: @cwallendpoole You are right of course.  The remark should have had a smiley. ;-)

Comment: Dear, Ray can  you show me a sample on how it suppose to work using the first method.

Comment: @user837306 There are examples on this page http://www.tizag.com/cssT/background.php

Comment: Dear Ray,If I use the example method will I have problem later when I want to impose drag and drop functionality to the image?

Comment: I have tried some thing like this but the problem it alignment with the rest it out and only partial of the image is shown<html>
<head>
<style>
p { 
background-image: url('tyre2.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;

 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div style="margin: 0; padding: 0;"><p>
Tyre</p>
<img src="longJoin.png" vspace="0">
<img src="tyre2.png">
</div>

Comment: I would place the image in a span, styled so that it is big enough to hold the whole image, with position values of `center center`.  When doing drag and drop, operate on the whole span.  HTH.

Comment: Dear Ray, Here is my latest link with the draggable and droppable included http://183.78.169.53/tyre2/swap2.html. But I have tried many changes still failed to look clean like http://183.78.169.53/tyre2/page3.html. Any help please. What are the tweaking needed?

Answer (score 1):

You can put another image with the number on top of the tires. Alternatively,  if all the images are the same, you can set the image as a background for the `div/li/a`and print the number as plain text.

If every picture is different,  you can assign every `div` (or whatever it is) an I'd, and echo custom CSS that sets a different background image for each div.

Comment: Dear Eric, Say I got another image with the number called as R1.png. So how is this image should be in the codes. I dont get your idea clearly.

Comment: Do inspect elements on the navigation menu [here](http://Jpspets.com) .  You'll see what I mean.

Comment: Dear Eric, Just to confirm is this what you meant <li style="background-image: url("templates/default/images/Button.jpg");">
<a id="active_menu" class="mainlevel" href="/home.html">Home</a>
</li>? Must I build a Li too is it?

Comment: Dear Eric, I have tried something like this.But only the word home comes out but the image does not appear?<div style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
 
<ul>
<li style="background-image: url("tyre2.png");">
Home
</li> 
</ul>
 
 
<img class="imgClass1" src="longJoinAxle.png" >
<img class="imgClass1" src="tyre2.png" >
</div>